# A convexity argument

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(\alpha_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers s.t. $\sum \alpha_n=1.$
Consider a sequence of complex numbers $(\beta_n)$ s.t  $|\beta_n|=const$ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Suppose that  $\sum \alpha_n\beta_n=\gamma$ where $\gamma\in \mathbb{C}$ and $ |\gamma|=|\beta_n|, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$ I want to prove that $\beta_n=\gamma, ~\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$

**Comments:** I can prove this fact when the sequence $(\beta_n)\subset \mathbb{R},$ in fact is sufficiently suppose that for some $n_0$ we have that  $\beta_{n_0}$ with $|\beta_{n_0}|<\gamma$ and use the condition $\sum \alpha_n=1$ in order to have that $\sum \alpha_n\beta_n< \gamma$ obtaining an absurd.

However when $\beta_n \in \mathbb{C}$  I cant prove it.

Comment: If $(\beta_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $|\beta_n|$=const=$c$. isn't it automatically true that $\beta_n=\pm c$ for every $n$?

Comment: In fact, we need suppose that $\beta_n>0$ for all $n$, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "A convexity argument" ? @OEmpaladordeCabras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sum\alpha_n\beta_n=\gamma$ and $|\beta_n|=|\gamma|$ for every $n$, then
$$\left|\sum\alpha_n\beta_n\right|^2=|\gamma|^2=\left(\sum\alpha_n|\gamma|\right)^2=\left(\sum\alpha_n|\beta_n|\right)^2.\tag1$$
Now follow the proof of the triangle inequality for complex numbers: Expand the LHS of (1) to obtain
$$\left|\sum\alpha_n\beta_n\right|^2=(\sum_m\alpha_m\beta_m)(\sum_n\alpha_n\bar\beta_n)=\sum_n\alpha_n^2|\beta_n|^2+2\sum_{m<n}\alpha_m\alpha_n\Re(\beta_m\bar\beta_n)\tag2$$
and compare this with the RHS of (1):
$$
\left(\sum\alpha_n|\beta_n|\right)^2=\sum_n\alpha_n^2|\beta_n|^2+2\sum_{m<n}\alpha_m\alpha_n|\beta_m\beta_n|\tag3
$$
The difference (3)-(2) is zero. Since $|z|-\Re (z)\ge0$ for any complex $z$, we deduce that $$\Re (\beta_m\bar\beta_n)=|\beta_m\bar\beta_n|\text{ for all }m\ne n.\tag4$$
Convert (4) to polar form and deduce that $\beta_m$ and $\beta_n$ have the same argument (angle) for every $m\ne n$, which implies the $\beta_n$ are all equal.

Comment: I apologize in advance, but your hint  are not clear enough   for me, can you explain-me a little bit more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OEmpaladordeCabras I have edited my answer to add more detail.